# What verb is best used to remedy/fill/... a lack of something?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What verb would you use to describe solving the problem of there being a lack of something?
For example, if there is a lack of money, and someone makes a donation, they would have ... the lack of money?

According to Google Ngram viewer, remedy would be best choice out of fill,remedy,resolve and compensate, but I wonder if there's a better alternative.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I was unclear, but I'm looking for a verb to use before the phrase "a lack of something", that indicates the lack is no longer there.

Comment: For example, in scientific articles you could see "The proposed methodology may be extensible to similar tools and tries to fill the lack of scientific studies in the validation and acceptance of computer-based educational tools." or "To remedy this lack a comprehensive survey has been carried out of the geochemistry of the large...". Are fill or remedy the best options here?

Comment: _avert_ / _obviate_, perhaps?

Comment: I was thinking 'resolve', but 'remedy' is probably better. I'm not sure if you will get a formal answer, as this appears to be either a General Reference issue, or possibly Primarily-Opinion-Based....

Comment: *Remedy* is good if the lack has occurred; *obviate* perhaps better if you mean the lack was remedied or prevented from occurring.

Comment: BTW @DjinTonic Welcome to the site. You came on board while I was on hiatus...but your contributions are outstanding.

Comment: Thank you, @Cascabel -- very kind of you. I had a rocky [start](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571447/are-there-cases-where-a-closing-quotation-mark-has-no-matching-opening-one), but I think I've found my sea legs :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose a different verb from 'fill' in the commented example. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/address) has

> **address**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **3** Think about and begin to deal with (an issue or problem)
>
> *a fundamental problem has still to be addressed*

Which rephrases the sentence as

> The proposed methodology may be extensible to similar tools and tries to **address** the lack of scientific studies in the validation and acceptance of computer-based educational tools.