# Is there an accepted convention on using parenthesis around multiple paragraphs?

Tags: parentheses

Years ago, I remember reading a novel (I think it was The Three Musketeers, maybe?) that had a few paragraphs inside parenthesis, and it followed the convention for a multiple paragraph quotation:

(Paragraph 1.
(Paragraph 2.
(Paragraph 3.)

So I'm curious, is this actually a convention? Google search seems to be failing me here.

I'm asking entirely out of curiosity, by the way.  I don't currently have any intention of using a multiple paragraph parenthetical in my own writing.

Comment: This would be a matter of style, and vary according to which style guide you were following, but I can't imagine any editor would approve of multiple paragraphs being formatted as a parenthetical. Either you integrate it into the text or put it in an appendix. I cannot think of a situation in modern writing where that practice could be justified.

Comment: Not Paragraph 1.)
Paragraph 2.
Paragraph 3.? {One for all and all for one.}

Answer (score 0):

This is the convention for quotation marks. I haven't seen it for parentheses, but it's a reasonable parallel.

See [How should I use quotation marks in sections of multiline dialogue?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/how-should-i-use-quotation-marks-in-sections-of-multiline-dialogue)